# Where to reference a javascript file in a aspx page that rely on a MasterPage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I know that it's recommended that that Script tags to reference javascript files should be put all the way to the bottom.

In the case of **Webform**, where am I supposed to place those tags, inside the **Maincontent** placeholder? Are they going to but put on the bottom by the MasterPage?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
  //css files can go here...
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="maincontent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

The reason I'm asking is because I don't want to use Jquery in the master page as it's messing up with the rest of the page. I want to run it only on those handful of pages.

Thansk for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever you put it, it needs to be above any OTHER script that uses it.   is preferable but nowadays is more of a convention than a requirement.

Comment: If I add the script on the bottom of the `maintcontent` placeholder, is it going to fine?

Answer (score 1):

Create another content placeholder for scripts in your master page (at the bottom). For example,

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
  //css files can go here...
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="maincontent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="scripts" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: If I add the `Content4` tag, I'll need to add the tags on every page using the `master page`, won't I?

Comment: Its not mandatory to add content to placeholder in every page.